# Infinite loop caused by ordering Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I try to  delete a record from my model I have this error:

> Infinite loop caused by ordering

```
class Empresa(MPTTModel):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=35, unique=True, db_index=True)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('Empresa', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children')
    nivel = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = ['nivel']
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['parent__id']
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the reason of this line `ordering = ['parent__id']` ?

Comment: if I dont put this line i have the same error in admin all the time, whit this line i have the error only on delete

Answer (score 5):

have you tried to use `self` ?

```
 parent = TreeForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children'
```

and remove

```
`ordering = ['parent__id']`
```

Comment: did you removed all related code (signal handlers, custom save/delete) ?